# Making Collection items appear in word VBA

Tags: vba, collections, ms-word

I have created a big macro in MS Word VBA that loops through many tables and inline shapes and with the help of copy-paste rearranges them after some manipulation. The problem arises when more than 50-60 tables and shapes, the macro takes 60 seconds to finish and i get random crashes (about 10-20% of the time) that i suspect come from clipboard overload issues and too much use of "Select". It was suggested to me to just use collections to store the shapes and tables (which worked) and improve the code, that i am currently trying to do, but i cant find the method or way to make the collection items appear in Word.

I am asking for something like collect(1).Show, which would work at the current selected paragraph or at least a collect(1).PlaceIt(there) method that i can input the coordinates of paragraphs i want the Shape or Table to appear in.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem? Not the full project, with reams of code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. It works with any collection such as tables/inlineshapes, even my custom collections.

```
Selection.Range.FormattedText = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Range.FormattedText
```

Instead of selection it can be used with paragraphs for example

```
Parahraphs(1).Range.FormattedText = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.FormattedText
```

It makes the objects from the collection to appear at the desired place (as copies, doesnt delete the original ones). This method is way faster than copy and paste. My script is now about 4 times faster (~62 sec -> 17 sec with about 60 tables and 60 inlineshapes) and i dont get the random clipboard errors when i use too many tables/charts.